# Search function: how to show the tables again, after deleting the search?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an search function which does sometimes work (and sometimes not haha). When I search for a fruit or a vegetable, which does exist in one of the tables it kinda works. If I delete the search input not all table rows appear again. Why?:(

If I now search for a word that doesn't exist at all, the search function hides all tables, which of course is exactly what it is supposed to do. BUT when I delete the search input the tables doesn't show again.

I don't know why its not working. Any ideas?

FIY the code isn't mine, I got it from the internet but I already tried a lot to make it work but it still doesn't. So I am asking for your help

```js
$("#search").keyup(function() { // search function
    var txtVal = $(this).val();
    if (txtVal != "") {
        $(".customize").show();
       // $(".message").remove();
        $.each($('.customize'), function (i, o) {
            var match = $("td:contains-ci('" + txtVal + "')", this);
            match.parent().siblings().hide();                         //  <<=== [LINE ADD]
            if (match.length > 0) $(match).parent("tr").show();
            else $(this).hide();
        });
    } else {
        // When there is no input or clean again, show everything back
        $("tbody > tr", this).show();
    }
    /*if($('.customize:visible').length == 0)
    {
        $('#search').after('<p class="message">Not found</p>');
    }*/
});

// filter
$.extend($.expr[":"], {
    "contains-ci": function (elem, i, match, array) {
        return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || $(elem).text() || "").toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  

<div>
    <label>
        Search: <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search">
    </label>
</div>


<div>
  <table  id="tableId" class="customize" boder="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2" id="th-header">Fruit Name</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr id="td-data-1">
        <td class="rowStyle">Banana</td>
        <td class="infoStyle">Info Text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="td-data-2">
        <td class="rowStyle">Orange</td>
        <td class="infoStyle">Info Text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="td-data-3">
        <td class="rowStyle">Apple</td>
        <td class="infoStyle">Info Text</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div>
  <table  id="tableId" class="customize" boder="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2" id="th-header">Vegetable Name</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr id="td-data-1">
        <td class="rowStyle">Potato</td>
        <td class="infoStyle">Info Text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="td-data-2">
        <td class="rowStyle">Bean</td>
        <td class="infoStyle">Info Text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="td-data-3">
        <td class="rowStyle">Onion</td>
        <td class="infoStyle">Info Text</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `$(".customize").show()` to show everything.

Comment: wow! Thank you!

Comment: @Barmar Would you mind writing your comment  as  an answer so it can be accepted?

Answer (score 0):

You should show everything the same way you do it before you filter when the search is filled in, with `$(".customize").show();`. You're just showing the rows, but not the tables.

```
$("#search").keyup(function() { // search function
    var txtVal = $(this).val();
    if (txtVal != "") {
        $(".customize").show();
       // $(".message").remove();
        $.each($('.customize'), function (i, o) {
            var match = $("td:contains-ci('" + txtVal + "')", this);
            match.parent().siblings().hide();                         //  <<=== [LINE ADD]
            if (match.length > 0) $(match).parent("tr").show();
            else $(this).hide();
        });
    } else {
        // When there is no input or clean again, show everything back
        $(".customize").show();
    }
    /*if($('.customize:visible').length == 0)
    {
        $('#search').after('<p class="message">Not found</p>');
    }*/
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet filters the table according to the first column's content. I left out the `if(txtVal!=""){...}` statement, as I built it into the argument of the `jQuery.toggle()` call in the `.each()` loop:

```
txtVal===""||o.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(txtVal)
```

This expression checks whether the lower-case value of the `#search` input field is empty or is contained in the lower-case `o.textContent` of the current `<td>`. It evaluates to either `true` (the table row is to be shown) or `false` (table row to be hidden). In both cases `$(o).closest("tr").toggle()` will carry out the required action on the closest parent-`<tr>` relative to each `<td>`-element `o`.

```js
$("#search").on("input",function() { // search function
  var txtVal = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $.each($('.customize tr td:nth-child(1)'), function (_,o) {
    $(o).closest("tr").toggle(txtVal===""||o.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(txtVal)); })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  

<div>
    <label>
        Search: <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search">
    </label>
</div>


<div>
  <table  id="tableId" class="customize" boder="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2" id="th-header">Fruit Name</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr id="td-data-1">
        <td class="rowStyle">Banana</td>
        <td class="infoStyle">Info Text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="td-data-2">
        <td class="rowStyle">Orange</td>
        <td class="infoStyle">Info Text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="td-data-3">
        <td class="rowStyle">Apple</td>
        <td class="infoStyle">Info Text</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div>
  <table  id="tableId" class="customize" boder="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2" id="th-header">Vegetable Name</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr id="td-data-1">
        <td class="rowStyle">Potato</td>
        <td class="infoStyle">Info Text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="td-data-2">
        <td class="rowStyle">Bean</td>
        <td class="infoStyle">Info Text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="td-data-3">
        <td class="rowStyle">Onion</td>
        <td class="infoStyle">Info Text</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Taking snippets "from the internet" is good for inspiration, but you should always try to understand them and make them your own. In this case the resulting code is much shorter and easier to maintain.